# Python Paramiko shell invoke insert unwanted characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, network-programming, paramiko, cisco

I am writing this after spending quite some time in searching it on available internet resources. I have a simple program which ssh into a cisco routers device to do a configuration changes. Whenever I run my program I see cisco cli(terminal) says invalid command it is because there is some character inserted in my command.

```
cisco-nexus(config)# username edwin password THISisWHERIAMtypingPWD<0x08>NG 
% Invalid command at '^' marker.
cisco-nexus(config)#
```

whilst the command which I am sending only contains following text:

```
username edwin password THISisWHERIAMtypingPWDNG
```

I have no idea how paramiko is inserting this randome code <0x08>.

completed code is here:

```
import paramiko
import time
import re

class ssh:
    def __init__(self, ip, user, pwd):
        self.ip = ip
        self.user = user
        self.pwd = pwd
    def device_conn(self):
        remote_con = paramiko.SSHClient()
        remote_con.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        remote_con.connect(hostname=self.ip, username=self.user, password=self.pwd, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
        remote_ses = remote_con.invoke_shell()
        output = remote_ses.recv(1000)
        time.sleep(1)
        remote_ses.send("conf t"+"\n")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        remote_ses.send("username edwin password THISisWHERIAMtypingPWDNG"+"\n")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        output = remote_ses.recv(10000)
        print output


with open("device.txt","rb") as dev:
    for fw in dev:
        print fw.strip()
        ob = ssh(fw.strip(), "user", "pwd")
        output = ob.device_conn()
```

Comment: Did you try deleting the string in your code and typing it from the scratch? Just in case it really contains the "backspace" character and your code editor is not showing it.

Comment: Yes i have tried it but it didnt help.